# Adding Variables in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been working on a tkinter calculator which adds 2 numbers together. I am planning on making this more advanced by adding in set numbers that when you type a number in it multiplies the number by that set varible. However, even after extensive research I cannot find some help for my particular issue. Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

e1 = Entry(root)
e2 = Entry(root)
l = Label(root)
def callback():
    total = sum(int(e.get()) for e in (e1, e2))
    l.config(text="answer = %s" % total)
b = Button(root, text="add them", command=callback)
for widget in (e1, e2, l, b):
    widget.pack()
b.mainloop()
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Can you explain better what you want it to do? Maybe with an example?

Comment: What's the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables are easy to define. Just like assigning a name to your widgets you assign a name to a string, list, dictionary, tuple, array, integer and more.

For example if you wanted to created some predefined multiple using the value of a variable you could do something like `my_new_var = 2` and then plug my_new_var into a function that multiples the value of that variable by whatever int you want.

Here is some code with an example. Make sure you add 2 numbers together first and then use the multiply by 2 button.

```
from Tkinter import *
from functools import total_ordering
root = Tk()

total = 0
my_new_var = 2

e1 = Entry(root)
e1.pack()
e2 = Entry(root)
e2.pack()
l = Label(root)
l.pack()

def callback():
    global total
    total = sum(int(e.get()) for e in (e1, e2))
    l.config(text="answer = %s" % total)

def mulitply_by_two():
    global total
    total = total * my_new_var
    l.config(text="answer = %s" % total)

b = Button(root, text="add them", command=callback)
b.pack()
by_multiple = Button(root, text = "Multiply by {}".format(my_new_var), command = mulitply_by_two)
by_multiple.pack()

b.mainloop()
```